# Can I use the Stack Exchange logo when advertising for a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, support, stackexchange-2.0, legal

Can I use the Stack Exchange logo to promote a Stack Exchange site, as is suggested [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/477/can-we-get-a-graphic-design/493#493) for the RPG beta?

The legal says

> Use of Our Name or Logo in Advertising
>
> - Do use the most current logo where **applicable and permitted.**
> - Do use the proper name for our company, product, or service (see "Proper use of the Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange Name" below).
> - Do not use our logo **unless you have been granted special permission by Stack Overflow Inc.**
> - Do not use our name or logo in a way that might imply a false sense of partnership or endorsement with your product.
> - Do not use any name or logo that is similar to or might be confused with our name or logo.
> - Do not **distort or alter** our logo in any way.
> - Do not use our logo in a way that confuses our brand with another brand.
> - Do not use any other artwork from our network without explicit permission.

I would assume, given highlighted text, that I can't do this. Just want clarification.

Comment: In case no one official responds to this post, just email the team and ask permission. You are offering to help promote their business, which I am sure they will be cool with.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the rules, I would say no, you can't use it.

However, you could:

- Try to get permission for whichver logo is selected as the most popular, or
- Somehow go through the process of having one of the logos (or one designed by the SE team) be made official, in which case you could freely distribute it, or
- Distribute the cards with the name of the site written in text

For now I'd go for the 3rd option. I think it's more important to get the site out there somehow than jump ahead to work on marketing/branding (which I assume the SE team will be a part of if the site succeeds).

Comment: With the regards to the SE Logo I think you're right.  I think use of the other icon, which was legitimately purchased, would be fine.